# Google Cloud Endpoints REST Discovery Document missing format

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, gradle-plugin

I've upgraded to Cloud Endpoints 2.0 which no longer supports RPC. Therefore, I generated a new discovery document and used the service generator with the REST discovery doc as input in order to generate the client library for my iOS app.

Using the new REST discovery doc I am getting the following error when trying to generate the library:

```
~/workspace/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/Source/Tools/ServiceGenerator/build/Release/ServiceGenerator discovery/servUsApi-v1-rest.discovery --outputDir GTLAPI --gtlrFrameworkName GoogleAPIClientForREST

ERROR: Failure, exception: Looking at parameter 'creditKickbackKash:creditAmount', found a type/format pair of 'number/(null)', and don't how to map that to Objective-C
```

I was able to manually fix this by adding (in numerous places) in the discovery doc, the "format": "double" key and value for all double parameters. Notice creditAmount below is missing a format, like all other doubles.

The generated discovery doc looks like this:

```
"creditKickbackKash": {
 "httpMethod": "PUT",
 "id": "servUsApi.admin.creditKickbackKash",
 "parameterOrder": [
  "userId",
  "creditAmount"
 ],
 "parameters": {
  "userId": {
   "format": "int64",
   "location": "path",
   "required": true,
   "type": "string"
  },
  "creditAmount": {
   "location": "path",
   "required": true,
   "type": "number"
  }
 },
 "path": "creditKickbackKash/{userId}/{creditAmount}",
 "response": {
  "$ref": "ResultDTO"
 },
 "scopes": [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
 ]
}
```

Is anyone else having this issue? How can I get the discovery document generation to properly format the document including double number types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I rolled back from 1.9.50 to 1.9.48 and the problem is gone.